# References to programming languages based on conditional logics

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, pl.programming-languages, type-theory, proof-theory

Conditional logics are logics which augment traditional logical implication with modal operators corresponding to other notions of condition (for example, the causal conditional $A\; \square\!\!\!\!\to B$ reads "$A$ causes "B", or probabilistic conditioning "$A|B$", which reads "$A$ given $B$").

Typically these logics are studied model-theoretically, but I've wondered about their applications to programming language design (for example, to type imperative actions).

I'd appreciate references to their proof theory (ie, sequent calculus/natural deduction), or to programming languages with types based on these kinds of modal operators.

Thanks!

EDIT: The Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy has a [nice introduction to the subject](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-conditionals/).

Comment: Hello Neel, this sounds quite interesting. 
I tried to Google "conditional logics" but  couldn't find much. Could you please suggest an introductory paper or something to know more about CL? thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check these references:

Programming languages CondLP and CondLP+:

Gabbay, Giordano,  Martelli, Olivetti, Sapino, Conditional reasoning in logic programming,  Journal of Logic Programming, Volume 44, Issues 1-3, 1 July 2000, Pages 37-74

Claudia, Oliveira, The implementation of CondLP, Lecture Notes in Computer Science, 1996, Volume 1085/1996, 713-715

Gabbay, Giordano, Martelli, Olivetti, Conditional logic programming, Proc. 11th Int. Conf. on Logic Programming, Santa Margherita Ligure, pages 272–289, 1994.

References to proof theory:

Olivetti, Pozzato, Schwind, A sequent calculus and a theorem prover for standard conditional logics, Journal ACM Transactions on Computational Logic (TOCL), Volume 8 Issue 4, August 2007

Comment: Thanks, this looks very interesting! I was hoping to see some functional or imperative languages rather than logic languages, though.

Answer (score 3):

[Church](http://projects.csail.mit.edu/church/wiki/Church) might be the kind of thing you are looking for -- it is functional (scheme derivative), but is designed with a probabilistic semantics, and implements conditional probabilities using "query" for doing Bayesian inference.  [Discussion of conditioning in Church](http://projects.csail.mit.edu/church/wiki/Conditioning).  This is (as I understand it) more or less the main operation in most Church programs.

To Matteo Mio: you might also be interested in Graham Priest's book, "An introduction to non-classical logic", which is centered around defining different types of conditionals.